# Problems with using gmapping - cannot launch node

Tags: ros, navigation, robotino, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I request your help in getting started with gmapping on robotino. I have just checked out the robotino-ros-pkg using svn and run 'rosmake robotino' without any errors. Now when I want to launch gmapping using: roslaunch robotino_navigation gmapping.launch, I get the following error:

```
sam3891@sam3891-ThinkPad-SL400:~$ roslaunch robotino_navigation gmapping.launch
========

PARAMETERS
* /rosdistro: indigo
* /rosversion: 1.11.10
* /slam_gmapping/xmax: 20
* /slam_gmapping/xmin: -20
* /slam_gmapping/ymax: 20
* /slam_gmapping/ymin: -20

NODES
/
slam_gmapping (gmapping/slam_gmapping)
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [9008]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 3968f884-97fe-11e4-a8ea-0026186f16cc
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [9021]
started core service [/rosout]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gmapping/slam_gmapping]: gmapping
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/usr/include/pcl-1.7/
ROS path [2]=/home/sam3891/robotino-ros-pkg
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

Is there any step that I am missing between download the robotino-ros-pkg and implementing gmapping? Do I need to download any extra packages? If so, how do I link it to ROS?
Can someone help please?

Here is the gmapping.launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node name="slam_gmapping" pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping">
    <param name="xmin" value="-20" />
    <param name="xmax" value="20" />
    <param name="ymin" value="-20" />
    <param name="ymax" value="20" />
  </node>
<!-- Run rviz -->
<include file="$(find robotino_navigation)/launch/rviz.launch" />
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200677/problems-with-using-gmapping---cannot-launch-node./) by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-01-10**:
From the error it seems your ros package paths are not defined properly. Also share the contents of you launch file to know which nodes you are trying to run. Did you sourced your bashrc file with correct ros package path before launching the gmapping node?

**Comment by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) on 2015-01-11**:
Hi, the problem is I am not able to find the gmapping node. There are no source files in the 'robotino_navigation' folder. So my question is, do I need to download something else (some other package) to get Gmapping running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my problem by downloading the openslam_gmapping dependency ("http://wiki.ros.org/openslam_gmapping?distro=indigo") and then building it in the catkin workspace using "catkin_make". This generated an executable in the devel folder, which I copied and placed into the "bin" folder of "robotino_navigation".

---

Originally posted by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) with karma: 46 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not used the module yet, but I guess you have just downloaded the repo from here:? https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping
If so, you have to put the folder into your workspace's src folder and compile it with `catkin_make`. Then you can source your workspaces devel/setup.bash.

Do the same with the robotino-pkg

---

Originally posted by [cbandera](https://answers.ros.org/users/21387/cbandera/) with karma: 123 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) on 2015-01-15**:
Yes I tried it and got this error:

```
         Could not find a package configuration file provided by "openslam_gmapping"
           with any of the following names:

openslam_gmappingConfig.cmake
openslam_gmapping-config.cmake
```

**Comment by [learner88](https://answers.ros.org/users/25005/learner88/) on 2016-01-14**:
use the package here to solve the openslam problem: https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping.git